# Behaviour of TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer when demoting write-lock to read-lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++builder

The following code causes my application to freeze, even though the program only has one thread running.

`semaphore` is a `boost::shared_ptr<TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer>`.

```
if (semaphore)
{
  semaphore->BeginWrite();

  // Perform write operations on the shared object here.

  semaphore->BeginRead();
  semaphore->EndWrite();

  // Perform read-only operations on the object, allowing other threads to also read.

  semaphore->EndRead();
  semaphore->BeginWrite(); // Program locks up here.
}
```

---

**Debug Information**, for @v.ouddou comment.

When I am stepping through the code, there is just one thread.  This is a windowed application by the way, so the program entry point is WinMain, if that matters).

When I step into the line of death (the last `semaphore->BeginWrite()`, the program freezes and if I stop it, then there are two threads.  My main thread is in assembly land but the call stack is `WaitForSingleObject`->`WaitForSingleObjectEx`->`ZwWaitForSingleObject`.

There is also a second thread with no stack information, at the entry point of  `RtlUserThreadStart`.  I assume this thread is just being made for the sake of me being able to pause the application though.  Nothing in my code makes sense to create a second thread at this point.

Comment: if you can run in debug, then hit the "pause" of the debugger, then you can inspect the stacks of all running threads in the process, and check where they are. If there is only your  main thread, it is possible that the stack will not be meaningful, in the case of the thread being on a de-scheduled call. like a semaphore wait for a signal. in this case, the thread goes to waiting queue and the OS immediately schedules something else instead, your stack makes generally no sense in such cases.

Comment: Basically this seems to be a bug in the implementation of TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer. However the use case where you FIRST call `BeginRead` then quite the write lock (`EndWrite`) and only then call `EndRead` is pretty strange anyway. Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: @v.oddou Added some info in response to what you said.

Comment: @Daniel The code I posted was meant as a minimal example.  After the first `BeginWrite()`, the main thread is intended to modify a shared object.  The following `BeginRead(); EndWrite();` is intended to  downgrade the lock from a write lock to a read lock.  The thread then sends notification to child threads that something has changed and they need to respond to the fresh data.  After all clients have been notified, we don't need to worry about the shared data changing anymore, so we release the read lock with `EndRead();`.  The final `BeginWrite();` is just there to replicate the issue.

Comment: The point is, 'EndWrite(); BeginRead();` has the same functionality (leave the write lock, enter a read lock). Please note that there is ALWAYS the possibility that another writer will get the write lock when upgrading or downgrading the lock! (This is inherent functionality to avoid deadlocks)!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have fixed the problem.  It requires adding a critical section to guard against deadlock during the reads however.

```
// Care: Two threads attempting to acquire the locks here would deadlock.
critical_section->Acquire();
semaphore->BeginRead();
semaphore->BeginWrite();
critical_section->Leave();

// Perform write operations on the shared object here.

semaphore->EndWrite();

// Perform read-only operations on the object, allowing other threads to also read.

semaphore->EndRead();

semaphore->BeginWrite(); // No longer deadlocks.
```

Comment: Actually the critical section isn't required. The "Fix" was to reorder the `BeginRead` and `BeginWrite` (old code was `BeginWrite`, `BeginRead`, `EndWrite`, `EndRead`. Which is the unsupported case)